# Netbeans: Java module installed but can not create a Java project, why?

Tags: java, netbeans, project

So I have been experiencing this problem for a while. I can use my existing java projects which I created on my PC, but on my laptop I can't create new Java projects. I reinstalled the program & reinstalled modules several times.

So when I click on new project, every java-type project is in the list except the regular one called 'java'... And the funny thing is that Java is the only project type I need at the moment, but it's simply not showing up..

I've looked on the internet for an answer but all I could find was one topic which was unanswered.

Help would be appreciated, a lot.

EDIT: OS: windows 7 64 bits. Using Netbeans 7.2 I think, well the newest for sure.

Comment: And JDK 1.7 one assumes. If you did have a prior 7 version, it would be best to delete them (on Linux a .netbeans/netbeans7.2 directory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you left out the OS you are using and you didn't mention the version of netbeans you tried!

You should completely uninstall netbeans. On UNIX OSes you'll find the `.netbeans` Folder in your homedir where netbeans keeps a lot of information. Remove this folder too (I don't know where this folder is stored on Windows OSes).

Having removed both netbeans and this folder, try a re-installation. Now things should look much better!

Comment: I had already done that, didn't work.. P.S.: Added OS info to main post!

Answer (score 4):

I just solved this problem by simply deleting `.netbeans` folder in `User\<User>\` and `.superId` in `\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\`

No need to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have installed multiple JDK (JDK version 8 and 9) due to which Netbeans 8.2 might not working as expected and then I was unable to create project.

Then I removed JDK9 and cleared cache from \Users\admin\AppData in windows.

Then I was able to create Java Project.